# hibernate exception regarding dialect

Tags: hibernate

## i m new to hibernate this is my first hibernate program plz help me to resolve this exception.i m just trying to connect my existing database in mysql.

```
    May 21, 2018 11:53:10 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.0.Final}
May 21, 2018 11:53:10 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 21, 2018 11:53:11 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
May 21, 2018 11:53:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 21, 2018 11:53:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice]
May 21, 2018 11:53:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
May 21, 2018 11:53:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 21, 2018 11:53:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
May 21, 2018 11:53:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySqlDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at test_class.Test_Class.main(Test_Class.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySqlDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
```

## my configuration file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">abhi</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySqlDialect</property>

    <mapping resource="resources/student.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

## mapping file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="beans.Student" table="college">
  <id name="id" column="s_id" />
  <property name="name" column="s_name" />
  <property name="mail" column="s_mail" />
  <property name="marks" column="s_marks" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

## test class to run that simple program is:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import beans.Student;

public class Test_Class
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Student st=new Student();
       st.setId(101);
       st.setName("abhimanyu");
       st.setMail("abh@gmail.com");
       st.setMarks(1235);
       Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
       configuration.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory factory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
       Session session= factory.openSession();
       session.save(st);
       session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

i even tried with chaanging the database name also but again getting same exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    change the parameters according to ur sql data  

  <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>

          <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
             org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          </property>

          <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
             com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
          </property>

          <!-- Assume test is the database name -->

          <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
             jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
          </property>

          <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
             root
          </property>

          <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
             root123
          </property>

          <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
          <mapping resource = "Employee.hbm.xml"/>

       </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>


    change the parameters according to ur sql data
```

Comment: yes sir, i did that nd  also checked after changing also...all my parameters and sql coloumn details are same and matched,but still i m getting the exception